# Mysql , spaces in REGEXP

Tags: mysql, regex, function

I have a problem.

This function of mine does all I want except one thing, it also removes the spaces from the string, this I don't want.

I've been trying all different tips and ideas from here but it doesn't work. The documentation says I'm using it correctly, maybe I misunderstood. Can someone please help me?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`%` FUNCTION `fn_RemoveNumbers`(str varchar(8000)) RETURNS varchar(767) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
  DECLARE i, len SMALLINT DEFAULT 1; 
  DECLARE ret varchar(767) DEFAULT ''; 
  DECLARE c CHAR(1); 
  SET len = CHAR_LENGTH( str ); 
  REPEAT 
    BEGIN 
      SET c = MID( str, i, 1 ); 
      IF (c REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]') OR (c REGEXP '[[:space:]]') THEN 
        SET ret=CONCAT(ret,c); 
      END IF; 
      SET i = i + 1; 
    END; 
  UNTIL i > len END REPEAT; 
  RETURN ret; 
END
```

The (c REGEXP '[[:space:]]') should in my eyes append the char to the final string but it doesn't.

I've also tried ' ', '[ ]' etc etc, without success.

I'm using mysql version 5.6. I used this doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't test UDF's here but try to make it 1 regexp like so:

```
IF c REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]|[[:space:]]' THEN
```

Is it possible that you're dealing with non-standard spaces? Like non-line-breaking spaces? In that case, maybe this works to catch all white-space:

```
IF c REGEXP '[[:alpha:]]|[[:blank:]]' THEN
```

Or if you're only trying to remove the digits, like so:

```
IF c NOT REGEXP '[[:digit:]]' THEN
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer mate. Tried them all and even the NOT REGEXP '[[:digit:]]' will not work, when i read i was sure that was the solution. I also now tried c REGEXP '[[:digit:]]' = 0 but still the spaces wont be appended to the string. Seems like a stupid problem to have :)

Comment: That is REALLY weird. My only explanation is that it's not so much the regex. Maybe a MySQL setting that automatically trims variables? So you add a space to `ret` and some process goes _"oy! space at the end of this var, better cut it off!"_.

Comment: Found a solution now!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solutino on this page: [MySQL REGEXP - Removing white space and non-numeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844880/mysql-regexp-removing-white-space-and-non-numeric-characters)

```
CREATE DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` FUNCTION `fn_RemoveNumerics`(str VARCHAR(1000)) RETURNS varchar(1000) CHARSET latin1
BEGIN
  DECLARE counter INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE strLength INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE strChar VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT '' ;
  DECLARE retVal VARCHAR(1000) DEFAULT '';

  SET strLength = LENGTH(str);

  WHILE strLength > 0 DO
    SET counter = counter+1;
    SET strChar = SUBSTRING(str,counter,1);
    IF strChar REGEXP('[0-9]+') = 0
      THEN SET retVal = CONCAT(retVal,strChar);
    END IF;
    SET strLength = strLength -1;
    SET strChar = NULL;
  END WHILE;
RETURN retVal;
END
```

I simply just changed 'IF strChar REGEXP('[0-9]+') = 1' to 'IF strChar REGEXP('[0-9]+') = 0'

I still cant figure out why it doesnt work. Maybe it has something to do whit the repeater? This one uses a while to get the job don3e.....and it works!