# how to retrieve numeric from string in mysql

Tags: mysql

In mysql, how can I retrieve just integer values from following string.

```
businessdate_year_partition=2015/businessdate_month_partition=3/locationid_partition=10
```

Comment: SQL is a screwdriver.  You have a nail.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not storing strings like that. Break the key into a table column and assign the value to the field. Storing data in strings like that is not compliant with any NF. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

However, you can use nested replace functions to remove letters and characters. But you will be calling relpace ~40 times. The result wont be pretty either.

`replace(replace(replace(replace(COLUMN_NAME,' ',''),'(',''),')',''),'-','')`

Similar question to:
[MySQL REGEXP - Removing white space and non-numeric characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8844880/mysql-regexp-removing-white-space-and-non-numeric-characters)